# How to copy files to different buckets according to suffix in lambda handler

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

How to copy a file with csv in to another bucket

I have 3 buckets in AWS a)test  b)testjson  c)testcsv

I have upload data.json and data.csv to test bucket

After Uploading the file below things are happend

1. data.json file is copied to testjson bucket
2. data.csv file is copied  to testcsv bucket
3. data.csv has to insert into dynamodb
4. data.json has to insert into dynamodb

data.json

```
{
"emp_id": "3",
"Name" : "Madk"
"Company": "FB"
}
```

data.csv

```
emp_id,Name,Company
3,Madk,FB
```

Below is the code 4th one to put the json in to dynamodb which is working fine, I need to add the 1st 2nd and 3rd

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    json_filename = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=json_filename)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table = dynamodb.Table('employees')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)
    
    return 'file uploaded'
    #print (bucket,json_filename)
```

In this lambda handler only I need to copy .json into another bucket and .csv into another bucket, i wrote code for adding my json into dynamodb, same way i need to add for the content in the csv file to dynamodb

Comment: I don't understand what you try to do and what is your problem.

Comment: @Nons Is it working for you? If not, what issue are you facing? Are you simply asking how to copy a file between buckets in Amazon S3, or are you asking how to upload files to S3? Please edit your question to add more information rather than answering in a comment.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein, yes in this lambda handler only I need to copy .json into another bucket and .csv into another bucket, i wrote code for adding my json into dynamodb, same way i need  to add for the content in the csv file

Comment: @furas in this  lambda handler only I need to copy .json into another bucket and .csv into another bucket. i don't want to write another lambda landler

Comment: If you wish to copy an object from one Amazon S3 bucket to another bucket, use [`copy_object()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.copy_object)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein basically as in the question if json need to copy different bucket and if csv need to copy different bucket, this everything i need to write in one lambda handler.  Also i wrote the content in .json to dynamodb, like need to upload the csv data into dynamodb

Comment: The AWS Lambda function will be invoked once for each file created in Amazon S3. If both types of files are being stored in the same location, then your Lambda function will need to include an `if` statement to determine what it should do. For example, if the `Key` ends with `.json`, then process it as a JSON file and copy it to the right destination. Otherwise, if the Key ends with `.csv`, then do something different and copy it to somewhere else. This is code that you will write in the Lambda function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the design pattern, implement your logic and post if you face errors

```
import json
import boto3

s3_client = boto3.client('s3')
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    filename = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']
    if(filename.split('.')[1].lower()=='json'):
        moveJSON(bucket,filename)
    elif(filename.split('.')[1].lower()=='csv'):
        moveCSV(bucket, filename)

def moveJSON(bucket, filename):
    #Implement your logic to move to test bucket
    #Implement your logic to move to testjson bucket
    #Below is your current logic to move to dynamodb
    json_object = s3_client.get_object(Bucket=bucket,Key=filename)
    jsonFileReader = json_object['Body'].read()
    jsonDict = json.loads(jsonFileReader)
    table = dynamodb.Table('employees')
    table.put_item(Item=jsonDict)    
    return 'file uploaded'

def moveCSV(bucket, filename):
    #Implement your logic to move to test bucket
    #Implement your logic to move to testcsv bucket
    #Implement your logic to move to dynamodb
```

Comment: How if i upload data.json file then it has to copy to testjson bucket

Comment: yes write that copy command in moveJSON function adn json file can be copied to your desired bucket